# public constructor in a class without any modifier

Tags: java

When we make a class "Hoge" which access level is default,
 what is the difference between

```
 Hoge(){}
```

and

```
public Hoge(){}
```

?

I know that the class is not visible from other packages, but in that case,
how does that "public" works?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean with "works" ?

Answer (score 4):

See the [official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

```
                  Access Levels
------------+---------+---------+-----------+------
Modifier    |   Class | Package |  Subclass | World
------------+---------+---------+-----------+------
public      |     Y   |    Y    |     Y     |   Y
protected   |     Y   |    Y    |     Y     |   N
no modifier |     Y   |    Y    |     N     |   N
private     |     Y   |    N    |     N     |   N
```

Constructors are members of the class, access levels for constructors are treated the same as other members.

Comment: It seems the OP already knows that...

Comment: @assylias Then his question is very vague. As I understand it, this should answer him.

Answer (score 0):

**When a class member is public**, it means **it's visible to everyone *that can see the class*** (and not anyone else).

So, if your class is package-private, then its public members and package-private members have the same visibility, essentially.

The only difference I can think of is that if the class becomes public later on, the public members will become visible to everyone (along with the class), while the package-private ones will remain as they were.

Comment: *if your class is package-private, then its public members and package-private members have the same visibility, essentially.* => not really. See the duplicate I posted: a public subclass can be instantiated with the public constructor. With a package-private constructor it would not be possible.